# Detect click event on connection in raddiagram

Tags: vb.net, telerik, mouseevent, raddiagram

Am trying to do the simplest of things in winforms/vb using the RadDiagram ..

I cannot detect mouse click when clicked on a connection in raddiagram

Below is my simple test code -

> ```
> Dim acon As New RadDiagramConnection
> acon.StartPoint = New Point(10, 100)
> acon.EndPoint = New Point(50, 750)
> acon.Name = "Line"
> RadDiagram1.AddShape(acon)
> AddHandler acon.Click, AddressOf mme
>
> Private Sub mme()
>   MsgBox("LNE")
> End Sub
> ```